# Oracle SQL Developer Status Error Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection on linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently switched to ubuntu and when I installed and tried to create a connection on Oracle SQL Developers 22.2.1 I get a error
**Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**
Ive tried changing the ports and switching between JDK 19,17 and 11 non of them seem to fix the error, all the guides that i can find on this error seem to be specifically for windows.

any help is appreciated and apologies if I have couldnt explain my problem clearly.

Testing connection of server should produce successful but its giving  Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: where is the database running?

Comment: Typically this kind of error is caused by a firewall blocking access to the port.

Comment: @pmdba its running locally

Comment: Oracle server isn't certified to run on Ubuntu. There are hacks for it, but behavior isn't guaranteed. I've seen a lot of people complain about networking issues in particular. If you want predictable, certified responses, then you need to run Red Hat, Oracle Linux, or SuSE Enterprise Linux. Oracle Linux (a Red Hat clone) is free for use; I recommend that.